# Build path to deep object tree in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
const getObject = (container, id, callback) => {
    _.each(container, (item) => {
        if (item.id === id) callback(item);
        if (item.files) getObject(item.files, id, callback);
    });
}
```

that will get me the object inside an object such as this:

```
const structure = {
    id: 1,
    name: "Struct",
    files: [
        {
            id: 2,
            type: "folder",
            name: "assets",
            files: [
                {
                    id: 3,
                    type: "folder",
                    name: "important",
                    files: [
                        {
                            id: 4,
                            type: "folder",
                            name: "modules",
                            files: [
                                {
                                    id: 5,
                                    type: "folder",
                                    name: "foo",
                                    files: [
                                        {
                                            type: "file",
                                            name: "foo.js"
                                        }

                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    id: 6,
                                    type: "folder",
                                    name: "bar",
                                    files: [
                                        {
                                            type: "file",
                                            name: "bar.js"
                                        }

                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }

                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Example:

```
getObject(structure.files, 6, (target) => {
    console.log(target)
})  // returns { "id": 6, "type": "folder", "name": "items", "files": [ { "type": "file", "name": "bar.json" } ] }
```

My problem is that I need to get the "path" back to the initial element (`structure.files`). What is the best way to go around this?

For example in this situation, it would return `[1,2,3,4,6]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the classic function and this argument for the path in the callback for [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Return full path when the target is found.

```js
var structure = { id: 1, name: "Struct", files: [{ id: 2, type: "folder", name: "assets", files: [{ id: 3, type: "folder", name: "important", files: [{ id: 4, type: "folder", name: "modules", files: [{ id: 5, type: "folder", name: "foo", files: [{ type: "file", name: "foo.js" }] }, { id: 6, type: "folder", name: "bar", files: [{ type: "file", name: "bar.js" }] }] }] }] }] },
    path;

[structure].some(function iter(a) {
    if (a.id === 6) {
        path = this.concat(a.id);
        return true;
    }
    return Array.isArray(a.files) && a.files.some(iter, this.concat(a.id));
}, []);

console.log(path);
```

ES6 version with closure for the path collecting variable `p`.

```js
var structure = { id: 1, name: "Struct", files: [{ id: 2, type: "folder", name: "assets", files: [{ id: 3, type: "folder", name: "important", files: [{ id: 4, type: "folder", name: "modules", files: [{ id: 5, type: "folder", name: "foo", files: [{ type: "file", name: "foo.js" }] }, { id: 6, type: "folder", name: "bar", files: [{ type: "file", name: "bar.js" }] }] }] }] }] },
    path,
    iter = p => a  => {
        if (a.id === 6) {
            path = p.concat(a.id);
            return true;
        }
        return Array.isArray(a.files) && a.files.some(iter(p.concat(a.id)))
    };

[structure].some(iter([]));

console.log(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

More generic way of doing this. You **don't** need to check for specific `id` like the other answer! This will work even if you add more complex `structure`. Take a look.

I'm doing a recursive check and adding the `id` to the array which will be returned after going through all the possible paths. Hope it helps!

```js
const structure = {"id":1,"name":"Struct","files":[{"id":2,"type":"folder","name":"assets","files":[{"id":3,"type":"folder","name":"important","files":[{"id":4,"type":"folder","name":"modules","files":[{"id":5,"type":"folder","name":"foo","files":[{"type":"file","name":"foo.js"}]},{"id":6,"type":"folder","name":"bar","files":[{"type":"file","name":"bar.js"}]}]}]}]}]}

  function getId(obj, idArray) {
    var idArr = idArray ? idArray : []
    if (obj.files) {
      obj.id && idArr.push(obj.id)
      obj.files.forEach(function(nextObj, i) {
        if (nextObj.id)
         getId(nextObj, idArr)
       })
      return idArr
    }
  }
  console.log(getId(structure))
```

Comment: you get any nodes, not the path to a specific node, as the op want.

Answer (score 0):

```
const recurse = function (container, id) {
  console.log("Now on node:", container);
  if (container.id === id) {
    console.log("Found the child whose existence was foretold!", container);
    var path = [];
    path.unshift(container.id);
    return path;
  } else {
    console.log("Your princess is in another castle", container);
    if (container.files && container.files.length > -1) {
      for(let i = 0; i < container.files.length; i++) {
        var child = container.files[i];
        var possiblePath = recurse(child, id);
        if (possiblePath) {
          possiblePath.unshift(container.id);
          console.log("This is " + container.id + " reporting in, we have the child.", possiblePath);
          return possiblePath;
        }
      }
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

const getObject = function(container, id, callback) {
  console.log("Starting recursion, looking for id", id);
  var path = recurse(container, id);
  if (path && path.length > 0) {
    console.log("Path to target element found", path);
  } else {
    console.log("Target element not found.");
  }
  callback(path);
}
```